# USB 3 to SATA adapter: ASM1153 vs ASM225 performance?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive, sata

So I just got two 16TB Seagate Exos drives that I need to attach to my computer via USB. I have a couple of old Seagate Expansion enclosures from shucked 6TB drives - I tried them and they worked fine. On the PCB it says they are using ASMedia ASM1153 controllers.

I am also considering getting two UGREEN external enclosures that use the newer ASM225 chip.

I found the specs for both on ASMedia's website, but I can't really tell if the ASM225 will outperform the ASM1153 when we're talking about HDDs. The ASM1153 is limited to SATA 3 Gbps, which would be bad for SSDs, but these HDDs cannot even reach 300MB/s, so that shouldn't make a difference. What I'm more interested in is if there will be a difference in random performance. I guess I could order the UGREEN, compare, and if it's the same I can return it, but I wanted to ask here first if anyone happens to be an expert on these things.

The UGREENs are about $25 each and I prefer the look of the Seagate enclosures aesthetically, so if there is no difference in performance I will just stick with the old Seagate enclosures.

The HDDs will be connected to USB 3.1 Gen 1 ports (5 Gbps)

Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Random reads are going to be irrelevant for the controller.

It will spend so much time waiting for the drive to head to seek across the disk and the data to then be ready that a 3gbps and a 6gbps controller will make no real difference. HDD Random reads tend to fall down to less than 50MB/s and many I've seen are worse than 5MB/s at heavy random reads/writes. At that point the interface is 100% completely irrelevant.

The 6gbps will *only* matter for SSDs, as you've already mentioned an HDD is unlikely to saturate even a 3gbps connection.

If you have SSDs then you might care about the controller, for HDDs I would not care at all.